# File reading/writing with multiple orderings

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, alphabetical

I have a text file I read from that has a list of names already in alphabetical order. I want to read each name and put it in alphabetical order by the name's length in a new file I create.

I do not seem to have any problem reading from the original file and putting the names in the newly created file.

However, I need:

- all the name lengths of 1 to be listed in alphabetical order
- then the names of length 2
- then 3 and so on.

The code that I have right now gets all the right names for the lengths that I want, but it puts all the names in order of how they appear in the file being read from. My question is: how do I list all the names of length 1 and then all the lengths of 2 and so on in that order?

I also can not use anything to do with arrays.

```
This is what I get in the newly created file from the code i have.

A
Al
B
Bo
C
D
E
Ed
F
G
H
I
J
Jo
K
L
Lu
M
N
O
P
R
S
T
Ty
V
W
Wm

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Lab11 {
   public static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
   public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      PrintStream fileOut = new PrintStream(new File("results.txt"));
      int count1 = 0;
      int count2 = 0;
      int sum = 0;
      while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
         String name = fileInput.next();
         count1++;
         if (name.length() == 1) {
            count2++;
            fileOut.println(name);
         }
         if (name.length() == 2) {
            fileOut.println(name);
         }
         while (fileInput.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += fileInput.nextInt();
         }
      }
      System.out.println(count1);
      System.out.println(count2);
   }
}
```

Comment: So is the problem they are in the right order according to their length but not alphabetical?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what's in the file and the output you are expecting? Your class name `Lab11` indicates this is homework but what you've tried to explain seems a bit complicated to me, unless they've actually gone over the tools needed for the solution in class (maps, sets, sorting, etc).

Comment: So what i want it to do is add all the names of length 1 to the new file first, and then once it has done that, add all the names of length 2 and so on.  As you can see though it is in alphabetical order but not in order by their lengths.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by implementing a custom [`Comparator<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares the length(s) before comparing the `String` values (actually, it's a good idea to handle `null` as well) like

```
static class StringLengthComp implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            if (o2 != null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        } else if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        int r = Integer.valueOf(o1.length()).compareTo(o2.length());
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Then you can store the values in a [`List<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and then print to the file after execution. Also, I suggest you use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
            PrintStream fileOut = new PrintStream(new File("results.txt"));) {
        int sum = 0;
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
            String name = fileInput.next();
            names.add(name);
            while (fileInput.hasNextInt()) {
                sum += fileInput.nextInt();
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(names, new StringLengthComp());
        for (String name : names) {
            fileOut.println(name);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly I can not use arrays because we have not used them yet in my class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print them out in alphabetical order, you're going to need to hold all the names in a data structure (if you know how many names you're going to have, use array; if you don't know how many names you'll have, use an array list).

Once you have all the files in the container, you'll have to run through them again to sort them (there are a number of ways to do this - bubble sort being the simplest. Others that might be appropriate include selection sort and quick sort).

Finally, once they are all sorted, do a loop that goes through the list x times, where x is the longest amount of characters in the longest string in the list. Each time you go through the list, print out characters of a certain length.

Comment: Sadly I can not use arrays because we have not learned them yet in class, also the original file I am reading from already has all the names in alphabetical order. I just need to sort the names by their length.

Comment: In that case, you could just iterate through the file x+1 times. The first time to find out what the max length is, which you then use to determine how many times to go through the file. for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) if(name.length() == i) fileOut.println(name);

Comment: Wow that actually makes a lot of sense. Would i just put the for loop after my while hasNext.

Comment: Yeah. If I recall correctly, in order to read the file again, you'll have to close it and then reinstatiate the scanner. So, fileInput.close(); then fileInput = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));

Comment: Use your while has next, and then the for loop, and then within the for loop you'll have to do another while hasNext. The fact that you can't store these values in an array is a real bummer lol.

Comment: @istrikeanywhere If I am not mistaken, what Tim Kwist proposes is that you implement **Selection Sort**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort